# ASP.NET MVC 1 Linq to SQL Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this call:

```
List<Product> featProducts = 
    productsRepository.Products.Where(x => x.Featured == true).ToList();
```

It returns the following error: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

I find it very weird as I am making similar calls in other places and it all works fine. My app compiles with no issues so I do not understand what could be causing that. Below is the detailed stack trace.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Jean-Philippe

> Server Error in '/' Application. Specified cast is not valid.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidCastException: Specified
>   cast is not valid.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 50:         public ViewResult
>   Featured() Line 51:         { Line 52:
>   List featProducts =
>   productsRepository.Products.Where(x =>
>   x.Featured == true).ToList(); Line 53:
>   Line 54:             foreach (var p in
>   featProducts)
>
> Source File: G:\My Webs\clients\CBP\CBP APP\WebUI\Controllers\ProductsController.cs
>   Line: 52
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Single() +55
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetFloat(Int32 i) +38
>   Read_Product(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
>   +825    System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
>   +29    System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   collection) +7667540
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1
>   source) +61
>
>   WebUI.Controllers.ProductsController.Featured()
>   in G:\My Webs\clients\CBP\CBP
>   APP\WebUI\Controllers\ProductsController.cs:52
>   lambda_method(ExecutionScope ,
>   ControllerBase , Object[] ) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +17
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +178
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +24
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__7()
>   +52    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation) +254 
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__9()
>   +19    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters,
>   ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +192
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)
>   +399    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
>   +126    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +7
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +151
>   Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ViewExtensions.RenderRoute(HtmlHelper
>   helper, RouteValueDictionary
>   routeValues) +214
>   Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ViewExtensions.RenderAction(HtmlHelper
>   helper, String actionName, String
>   controllerName, RouteValueDictionary
>   routeValues) +315
>   Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ViewExtensions.RenderAction(HtmlHelper
>   helper, String actionName, String
>   controllerName) +10
>   ASP.views_pages_home_ascx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer) in g:\My Webs\clients\CBP\CBP
>   APP\WebUI\Views\Pages\home.ascx:12
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children) +256
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +19
>   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children) +134
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +19
>   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +59
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1266
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.4200;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the issue. It was irrelevant with my query.

It was in the product class. I was trying to match a sql server float with a .net float. It didn't like that. Using a .net double solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one ?

```
List<Product> featProducts = productsRepository.Products.Where(x => x.Featured == true).ToList<Product>();
```

Comment: Of COurse.

I can't believe that I haven't seen that. 

You know when you've been reading the same line so many times.

Thanks a lot.

Jean-Philippe

Comment: I got a bit too excited there. Sorry. 

It is still erroring.